# Подскажите как правильно создать список

Tags: java

у меня есть список команд

```
enum{
"init", "start", ..., "stop"}
```

а я хочу, что бы в таблице пользователю отображались не эти команды, а их описание на русском:
инициализация, старт, ..., стоп.
Как это проще (или правильней) сделать?
Можно ли это сделать используя enum (правда я не знаю как это реализовать) или лучше это сделать через мапу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum States {
    INIT("Инициализация"),
    START("Старт"),
    STOP("Стоп");

    private final String description;

    States(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```